# Flood fill algorithm looping ad infinitum

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, flood-fill

I'm trying to implement a simple flood fill algorithm to my game in order to find the size of a cavern in a procedurally generated cave; however, I appear to be missing some fundamental point and as such the algorithm I'm using continuously queues even checked points.
My code is as follows:

```
List<Point> sector = new List<Point>();
List<Point> checkd = new List<Point>();
List<Point> queue = new List<Point>();

queue.Add(new Point(startX, startY));

while (queue.Count > 0) {
    Point origin = queue[0];
    queue.RemoveAt(0);
    sector.Add(origin);
    checkd.Add(origin);

    for (int offsetX = -1; offsetX < 2; offsetX++) {
        for (int offsetY = -1; offsetY < 2; offsetY++) {
            if (offsetX == 0 && offsetY == 0 || offsetX == offsetY ||
                offsetX == -offsetY || -offsetX == offsetY)
                continue;

            Point target = new Point(offsetX, offsetY);

            if (target.X < 0 || target.Y < 0 ||
                target.X >= cells.Width || target.Y >= cells.Height ||
                !checkd.Contains (target))
                queue.Add(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: Create the `target` instance outside of the `while` loop. The way you're doing it can cause serious performance issues due to garbage collection. Also, replace the `while()` with a post-condition `do { } while()`, as the first comparison is unnecessary (since you've just seeded the queue when it executes.)

Comment: `checkd` should **absolutely not** be a `List` - `contains` requires checking each element, which is slow. Use a `HashSet` / `SortedSet` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things wrong here. I tried to preserve your original code as much as possible.

1. Target point calculation: `Point target = new Point (offsetX, offsetY);` does not compute the position. You probably want to use `Point target = new Point(origin.X + offsetX, origin.Y + offsetY);`
2. Checking out of bounds coordinates and if the point is already in `checkd` cannot be done in one if-statement as in `if (target.X < 0 || target.Y < 0 || target.X >= cells.Width || target.Y >= cells.Height || !checkd.Contains (target))` since that would also add points to the queue which are outside the `cells` grid.
3. Checking if the point is in the list by reference. Using `List<Point>.Contains(Point p)` only returns true if **the reference to** the point is already in the list. This is never the case since target is created as with `Point target = new Point(...)`.
4. Before adding the target point you may also want to check if that point is not already in the queue.

---

So here is my version. It travels through all points and eventually adds them to checkd.

```
List<Point> checkd = new List<Point>();
List<Point> queue = new List<Point>();

queue.Add(new Point(startX, startY));

while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    Point origin = queue[0];
    queue.RemoveAt(0);
    sector.Add(origin);
    checkd.Add(origin);

    for (int offsetX = -1; offsetX < 2; offsetX++)
    {
        for (int offsetY = -1; offsetY < 2; offsetY++)
        {
            // do not check origin or diagonal neighbours
            if (offsetX == 0 && offsetY == 0 || offsetX == offsetY || offsetX == -offsetY || -offsetX == offsetY) continue;

            Point target = new Point(origin.X + offsetX, origin.Y + offsetY);

            // skip out of bounds point
            if (target.X < 0 || target.Y < 0 || target.X >= cells.Width || target.Y >= cells.Height) continue;

            if (!Contains(checkd, target) && !Contains(queue, target))
            {
                queue.Add(target);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To check for containment I used the method:

```
private bool Contains(List<Point> list, Point point)
{
    return list.Any(p => p.X == point.X && p.Y == point.Y);
}
```

---

Trying to implement a flood-fill algorithm from scratch may be a good exercise. For a serious project you should consider using a graphics library which has this functionality (and probably more you will need) already implemented.

Comment: Whew, I must be having a pretty off day. While your third point turned out to be untrue (Point instances can be compared), everything else was working together to create one nightmare of a result. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jamie Glad I could help. About my third point: I was assuming `Point` is a class. In your case, `Point` must therefore be a struct.